# When running mocha test I get "object is not a function" but not when i run the test directly

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

when i run "**mocha**" to run all my tests i get this error:

```
var should = chai.should();                  ^
TypeError: Property 'should' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

However when I run "**mocha test/filename.js**" on the file in question it runs fine.
The **chai.should()** came from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874676/how-to-get-mocha-to-fail-a-test) I asked previously.

latest node/npm/mocha/chai/should

What would cause such discrepancy in such between the different runs?

thanks

Comment: Can you should your tests?

Comment: What does the `TypeError` point to?

Comment: on the .should() sorry should have been more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *appears* since mocha was loading **should** in earlier tests like,

```
var should = require('should');
```

and trying to use that **should** globally, so when it got to my

```
var should = chai.should();
```

in later tests it would bomb because it conflicted, so when running the test alone there was no conflict.

I solved this by going through all my tests and redefining my should requirement to the one above.