# Make mocha test fail in try / catch

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have the following function to validate a JSON file:

```
export const validateJSON = (sourceDir, fileName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        pricingService.processJSON(params, data)
          .then(data => {
            config.accounts.currencies.forEach(function (currency) {
              if (data[currency] === '' || data[currency] === undefined) {
                reject({err: 'Missing required values'});
              }
            });
            resolve('JSON Validation Success');
          })
          .catch(error => {
            logger.error({
              message: `Error while processing JSON, request Failed with Error: ${error}`,
            });
            reject({err: error});
          });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error({
        message: `Error while validating JSON file, request Failed with Error: ${error}`,
      });
      return reject({err: {status: 422, message: 'Error while validating JSON - Unprocessable Entity'}});
    }
  });
};
```

Now, I have a test in Mocha

```
it.only('Validate Pricing JSON file', function () {
        s3Service.validateJSON('',filename,Date.now()).then(data =>{
            setTimeout(() =>{
                assert.equal(data, 'JSON Validation Success')
                done()
            }, 1000)
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error("JSON validation failed "+JSON.stringify(error))
            throw error
        })
    });
```

What I am trying to do is to validate the JSON file in the test and if there is some fields are missing in the file, the test should fail. Now when I execute the test with a file with missing entries, I am getting the following error printed to console.

`JSON validation failed {"err":{"status":422,"message":"Error while validating JSON - Unprocessable Entity"}}`

```
(node:26091) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): #<Object>
(node:26091) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

But the test is shown as passed. How can I make it fail if there is an error ? Also how to get rid of the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` ? I am very new to Unit Testing and so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Testing Asynchronous Code](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous)
Maybe this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't throw an error.

Use `assert.fail`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539753/3107689)

Comment: It is also showing the test as passed.

Comment: @shawn is right, you should adapt your test for promise, it needs to be readable.

Comment: how can I do that? can you please show me an example?

Comment: BTW why do you even use try/catch? you want it to fail in case of an error, just run `it.only('Validate Pricing JSON file', s3Service.validateJSON('',filename,Date.now()))`

Comment: try catch is used in the actual function only. Not in the testcase.

Comment: i mean `then\catch`, they are the same