# Async test with inner async function should fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, mocha.js, ecmascript-2017

In my mocha.js test, I'm calling an `async` function that throws an error, but the test doesn't fail. It passes and there is an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`:

```
describe('async function', async function () {
    it('should fail', async function () {
        [1].forEach(async function () {
            throw new Error("Why can't I see this error?!");
        });
    });
});
```

Note, that a simpler case works as expected:

```
describe('async function', async function () {
    it('should fail', async function () {
        throw new Error('This one fails the test');
    });
});
```

How can I *cause* the test to fail due to an exception in an inner function?

(I've tried adding an `unhandledRejection` handler, but the test still passes)

Comment: Check out the thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879181/test-for-expected-failure-in-mocha

Comment: @MihaiAndrici, I didn't mention it to keep the question and code short, but in the original code it's actually not a `throw` but a failed Chai assert. The result is the same (`expect.fail()` will not cause the test to fail). But thank anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test case with `.forEach` cannot work like you want it to work. When it calls its async callback, the callback does create a promise, but `.forEach` does not do anything with it. The callback you pass to `it` is async too and it does return a promise, but the promise it returns is not connected to the promises that the callback to `.forEach` produces. That's why you get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

You can solve the issue by connecting the promises through `Promise.all`:

```
describe('async function', async function () {
    it('should fail', async function () {
        return Promise.all([1].map(async function () {
            throw new Error("Why can't I see this error?!");
        }));
    });
});
```

Using `map` makes it so that your array is turned into an array of promises, and then `Promise.all` waits for all the promises in the array to be resolved, or it rejects if any promise rejects. Returning the return value of the `Promise.all` call then allow Mocha to wait for the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

Louis' answer is spot on. As an alternative, you could avoid using an inner function and use a normal `for` loop instead:

```
const data = [1];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // await some more stuff here
  throw new Error('This one fails the test');
}
```